# hierarchy information while using grouped category plugin in highchart

Tags: highcharts

while using grouped category plugin,

```
   $('.highcharts-axis-labels text, .highcharts-axis-labels span').click(function () {
                            console.log(this.textContent || this.innerText);
                        });
```

the above code snippet would give info about the clicked xaxis label, is there a way to ascertain the parent of the same?

i would like to get the parent as "Forecast" when i click "Footwear" in the above chart
[image]

Comment: You can try to catch click on labels by [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) and then use loops to find a parent

Comment: Parent does not give info :(

Comment: am looking for something similar to this in lables http://jsfiddle.net/tAq9V/

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom-events extenstion and then add click event on xAxis labels. Name of parent can be extracted from textStr value.

```
labels: {
        events: {
            click: function () {
                alert(this.parent.label.textStr);
            }
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tAq9V/9/

Comment: In the above example. the click event does not respond on clicking the fruit in axis (i.e) the parent. Any ideas?

Comment: At this moment click events can be added only for the deeper level of children on xAxis. Feature which you mentios has an enhancement status.